# Radius of convergence is distance to the nearest singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

Can any one tell me please that whether Radius of Convergence of Power Series is distance to the nearest singularity from centre or distance to the nearest non-removable singularity to the centre? Or I want to know whether removable singularity matters or not?
Thanks

Comment: Removable singularity doesn't matter here.  Only poles and essential singularities are relevant here.

Comment: Thanks dear for clearing it.

Comment: There can be singularities that are not poles or essential ones (for example, algebraic or transcendental singularities).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $U$ is a non-empty open set in the complex plane, and $f$ is holomorphic in $U$. If $z_{0}$ is a point of $U$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}(z - z_{0})^{k}$ is a power series representation of $f$ in some neighborhood of $z_{0}$, then the radius $R$ of this power series is the radius of the *largest open disk $D(z_{0}, R)$ about $z_{0}$ into which $f$ (technically, the germ of $f$ at $z_{0}$) extends holomorphically*.

Since $f$ can be extended holomorphically over a removable singularity, the presence of a removable singularity does not affect the radius $R$. For example, if $f(z) = \frac{\sin z}{z}$ for $z \neq 0$, then for every non-zero $z_{0}$, the power series expansion of $f$ about $z_{0}$ has infinite radius.

**Caution**: There is no guarantee we can expand $\frac{1}{z}$ and $\sin z$ separately and multiply series, since the series for $\frac{1}{z}$ has finite radius.

On a related note, if $\log$ denotes a holomorphic branch of logarithm in some region $U$, and if $z_{0}$ is a point of $U$ (necessarily non-zero), the series representation of $\log$ about $z_{0}$ has radius $|z_{0}|$, the distance to $0$. In this sense, points of a branch cut are not necessarily "singularities".

**Caution**: It need not happen that $f$ is equal to the power series in all of $D(z_{0}, R)$, only in the largest disk contained in $D(z_{0}, R) \cap U$.